# I am not able to enter a email address in modal login form of my application using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class Login {
    WebDriver driver = new  FirefoxDriver();


    @Test
    public void test() {

            driver.get("http://www.urbanremedy.com/");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();

            driver.findElement(By.id("youama-email")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("youama-email")).sendKeys("abs");

            driver.findElement(By.name("youama-password")).sendKeys("123456");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div/button")).click();
        }
    }
```

Password works, only problems lies with email address. It's not reflected and hence I am stuck. Please do help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the email and password input elements are not visible (`style="display:none"`) and so the web-driver is unable to interact with them. If you click on the *Submit* button once, then they become visible (`style="display:block"`), and you can continue as planned from that point onwards.

BTW, you don't need to find each element "over and over" - you can find it once, and keep it in memory.

For example, instead of:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("youama-email")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("youama-email")).sendKeys("abs");
```

You can do:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("youama-email"));
e.clear();
e.sendKeys("abs");
```

Comment: I tried implementing the above suggestion, and there is no improvement. Is there anything which would be more helpful to solve this problem. And the problem is only with Email, Password input works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using By.xpath to locate the password rather than using By.name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a bigger project, I also highly recommend that you have a look at the Page Object pattern https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects.

It is a pattern which tries to encapsulate the web elements of a page and provide the services of the respective page as its methods.